# Mapping mapping level to background color in Emotion

Tags: emotion

I have a series of log lines, with corresponding levels in the set `{verbose,debug,info,warning,error,fatal}`

I'd like to map each level (based on the data of the line I'm rendering) to a colour. What's a nice way of expressing this in emotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [themes](https://emotion.sh/docs/emotion-theming) for that. Install the theming package:

```
yarn add emotion-theming
```

Here is a an example with React.

`App.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming'

import LogEntry from './LogEntry .js'

const theme = {
  color: {
    severity: {
      verbose: 'pink',
      debug: 'blue',
      info: 'teal',
      warning: 'orange',
      error: 'red',
      fatal: 'darkred',
    }
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LogEntry severity="info">Info :)</LogEntry>
        <LogEntry severity="warning">Warning!</LogEntry>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

`LogEntry.js`:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const LogEntry = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme.color.severity[props.severity]};
`

export default LogEntry;
```